# find anomalies in records of categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

I have a dataset with m observations and p categorical variables (nominal), each variable X1,X2...Xp has several different classes (possible values). Ultimately I am looking for a way to find anomalies i.e to identify rows for which the combination of values seems incorrect with respect to the data I saw so far. So far I was thinking about building a model to predict the value for each column and then build some metric to evaluate how different the actual row is from the predicted row. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: It will be better to post this question on http://ai.stackexchange.com

Comment: Let me understand well...so the criteria to understand if a record is uncorrect is based on the frequency of the terms inside that category? If a term occurs few times probably is uncorrect, is this your valutation? Could you show a sample of your data?

Comment: Basically I was thinking about an analogy with the market basket analysis. If  some values are often occuring together and that only one time one value seems too completely miss that pattern, I would like to flag that. Something like identifying outliers but for multiclass categorical data

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on nearest neighborhoods method and cluster analysis. Metric can be simple (like squared error) or even custom (with predefined weights for each category).

Nearest neighborhoods will answer the question 'how different is the current row from the other row' and cluster analysis will answer the question 'is it outlier or not'. Also some visualization may help (T-SNE).